# How to handle more complicated post requests in python/php?

Tags: php, python, dictionary, post, python-requests

I have a python program which uses requests. I want to upload data via post request like this:

```
payload = (('key1', 'value1'), ('key1', 'value2'))
r = requests.post("https://www.example.com/test.php", payload)
print(r.text)
```

In php I receive this data for testing like this:

```
<?php
echo var_dump($_POST);?>
```

In the example of the doc (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) this:

> print(r.text)

should be output this:

```
  "form": {
     "key1": [
       "value1",
       "value2"
     ]}
```

But in the output array value1 is missing:

```
    array(1) {
       ["key1"]=>
       string(6) "value2"}
```

Whats wrong here? Where is "value1"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your payload in the python

```
 payload = {'key1', ['value1', 'value2']}
```

this will help your payload with the same key have two values.

Comment: Same result when I use this version. And I think you mean it like this:
payload = {'key1': ['value1', 'value2']}
With this:  payload = {'key1', ['value1', 'value2']}
I get a TypeError